# How to do a log out action when using static cells in a table view?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, logout

I'm using Firebase and are trying to log out the user when the cell is pressed. For some reason I could not remove the label in the static cell table view, so I tried to add a button and hide the label.

[image]

Comment: Your button is in a cell , and you are declaring it's @IBAction in the Controller class... Declare your button action in your custom cell class

Comment: were you able to get the job done?

Comment: @Mr.Bista Nope.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to logout using cell selection:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        try FIRAuth.auth()?signOut()
    }
}
```

Second option, to make button action work change the cell style to Custom:

[image: Logout Cell]

Currently the Label is above the Button in the View Hierarchy, hence button action is not working.

Comment: I tried the second option, but I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong. This is what I have right now: http://oi66.tinypic.com/73mrut.jpg

Comment: Add a button to cell and also try to change cell style to custom.

Comment: I'm not able to add a button under the Table View Cell, it needs to be placed under the Content View. Here's the picture on imgur: http://imgur.com/4bKg72S

Comment: have you changed the button style to custom as shown in my answer?

Comment: Yes, the button style is changed to custom